# create docker image for deploying selenium application

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

im trying to install firefox + gechodriver on openjdk:8 but it fails to untar the downloaded firefix and create the simlink! can someone plase let me know what are the prerequisites for installing firefox?

Comment: Show what you tried and how it fails plz.

Comment: Why are you trying to create your own image? There is already a ready-made image of [firefox](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox)

Comment: thanks! i started using above mentioned docker image.